# Dockerfile base image

Tags: docker

I have a Python application that I want to containerize with Docker. Should I use `FROM python:3` or `FROM python:3.7`?

Does the `python:3` tag automatically use the latest minor version of Python? Would there be a practical reason to pin to version 3.7 explicitly?

I could not find a clear answer to these questions in the [official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).

Comment: When run use `python:3` it means you don't care about the minor version, if you do cares, then specify it. `docker run python:3 python3 --version` returns `Python 3.11.2` for me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when referencing 3rd party packages (Docker base images, Maven dependencies, Ruby Gems etc.) it is worthwhile to be as specific as possible. You want to avoid randomly upgrading dependencies at a later time, just because there's a newer version out there, just because you only specified a prefix of the actual 3rd party release number.

I personally would do whatever it takes to make sure that I get the same upstream version on every build, forever, and that upgrading always is an activity I have to d, that is never done for me. For example, in Ruby, the `bundler` keeps specific versions in the `Gemfile.lock`. While the `Gemfile` can specifiy vague versions (like "~> 3.1" giving you anything ">= 3.1 and < 4.0"), whenever a version is picked by the automatic resolving, the actual immutable version is fixed in the `Gemfile.lock` and will never change on its own.

The reasoning is very simple - we use tools like Docker specifically to get out of the upgrade/version hell we had in the past; to make sure that we have the same versions on all environments, and to make changes visible (in the form of `git` commits etc.). Introducing the same all over, by having "floating" upstream version numbers, would really be a shame.

There is really nothing elaborate like that Ruby `Gemfile.lock`, for Docker base images, so in this case you have to look at the images you are pulling; they should document which tags are considered permanent.  Then just specify those. And stay clear of `latest`, obviously.

For your particular example, to pick at random, a version like `3.6.6-alpine3.7` seems to be pretty fully specified. I'd expect not much more than bugfixes from upstream. But if I were especially paranoid on that day, I might specificy a `@digest` for the FROM (I'm not that paranoid normally...).

Answer (score 1):

From the official Docker hub repository at https://hub.docker.com/_/python/.

> Shared Tags
>
> - 3.7.0, 3.7, 3, latest:
>
>   - 3.7.0-stretch (3.7/stretch/Dockerfile)
>   - 3.7.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2016 (3.7/windows/windowsservercore-ltsc2016/Dockerfile)
>   - 3.7.0-windowsservercore-1709 (3.7/windows/windowsservercore-1709/Dockerfile)

Based on that, I assume version X will be a tag of latest X.Y.Z.